# jQuery: detect input change when selecting a value from the browser autocomplete

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have an input. I need to sanitize the input's string everytime the user changes the value. It works alright with this:

```
$('input#q').change(function(){
    //sanitize string here...
});
```

The problem is when the user clicks on the browser's autocomplete feature for that input. In that specific event, nothing happens. Is it possible to bind some kind of autocomplete to the #q input?

Comment: Seems like a browser bug almost. The trivial solution to this is to monitor the contents with an interval or something, but I generally dislike that approach. Remember though that you can't rely just on JS to do sanitization, it can be bypassed very easily.

Comment: Absolutely. Javascript sanitization is just for the eye candy ;) -- it seems there is no way to control this on an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the `paste` event:

```
$('input#q').bind('paste', function(e) { 
    alert('pasting!');
})
```